# ORM support for compound primary keys

Tags: .net, sql, orm, primary-key, compound-key

I've read that compound primary keys will [confuse the hell out of typical ORM code generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107404/what-are-the-down-sides-of-using-a-compositecompound-primary-key#108337). Which ORMs work best with compound PKs and which to avoid? (I've a particular interest in .NET)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using NHibernate successfully with compound keys.

```
<class name="UserProfileField" table="UserProfileFields">
    <composite-id>
        <key-many-to-one name="Parent" column="UserId" lazy="false"/>
        <key-property name="FieldName"/>
    </composite-id>
...
```