# Relational Database Design - double primary key in one table?

Tags: mysql, database-design, primary-key

I have a table that keeps the user ratings for items.
I want to allow each user to rate an item only once, is there any way to force the database not to allow duplicate for itemId and userId?

[image]

I don't want each individual field to be a primary key.
I want the primary key to be based on both of them at the same time.
for example there is a row:

```
itemId= 1 & userId = 1
```

following should be allowed:

```
itemId= 2 & userId = 1
itemId= 1 & userId = 2
```

following should NOT be allowed:

```
itemId= 1 & userId = 1
```

Comment: I'm suspicious of putting this logic in the database. Seems like it should belong with the rest of the validation code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Create a primary key on both itemId and userId.

To do this in T-SQL (SQL Server) you would use something like:

```
CREATE TABLE rating (
  itemId int NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT fk_rating_item FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES item ( itemId ),
  userId int NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT fk_rating_user FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [user] ( userId ),
  thumbsUp int,
  thumbsDown int,
  CONSTRAINT pk_rating PRIMARY KEY ( itemId, userId )
)
```

(This assumes your items table is 'item' and your users table is 'user'.)

I'm not sure why you have a value for both thumbs up and thumbs down? If this is a boolean value, you might only need one: if thumbs up is 0, then that's effectively thumbs down anyway.

**Edit: Definition of composite keys**

When you create a primary key on two columns in one table, that means it is only required to be unique for both values, i.e. it will allow for any number of rows with the same itemId as long as each userId is different, and vice-versa.

It's the combination of the two that must be unique, not each part of the key individually.

Comment: One downside of using compound primary keys is that if there are relationships to other tables, you can end up needing compound foreign keys as well. It may not be a factor in this example, but it can get complex in others. Say if each rating had many paragraphs and many attachments, each of which had their own table. Then those tables would need itemId and userId columns as well, and you'd have to be careful to use both keys in updates and queries. Alternatively, you can have a single surrogate key for the rating table, and enforce itemId, userId uniqueness with a constraint.

Comment: Alex, what you say is true. However, if you analyze the subject matter into entities and relationships, and tie all the attributes to this ER framework, and then tie the attributes together into relations in a fairly straightforward way, you end up with tables that never have entities referencing relationships or relationships referencing other relationships. At least, not at first.

Answer (score 0):

Most databases will allow for composite primary keys made from multiple columns.  Which database are you using?

An interesting, related discussion: [What are the down sides of using a composite/compound primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107404/what-are-the-down-sides-of-using-a-composite-compound-primary-key)

mySQL type example:

```
createuserratings.sql
CREATE TABLE USERRATINGS
( 
    itemId     INT NOT NULL,
    userId     INT NOT NULL,
    thumbsUp   INT NOT NULL,
    thumbsDown INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (itemID, userID)
);
```

Do a search for composite/compound primary keys in the mySQL documentation and you should get a lot of info (I don't use mySQL).

Answer (score 0):

Use a composite primary key (primary key consisting of 2 columns).

```
CREATE TABLE Rating 
(
 itemID     INT NOT NULL
,userID     INT NOT NULL
,thumbsUP   INT NOT NULL
,thumbsDown INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY (itemID, userID)
);
```

Comment: thanks, so what would i do differently if I didn't want to have a composite primary key?

Comment: I would say that you wouldn't do anything differently. Rating is a junction table and in this context, is the only way to establish a relationship between the User table and Item table.