# Multiple foreign keys per record in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I'm creating an application (using PHP / Codeigniter / MYSQL) for tracking volunteers at events. I'd like multiple volunteers to be able to sign on to each event. I plan on doing this using a table called `signup` which looks something like this:

```
TABLE SIGNUP
============

VolunteerId         EventId
-----------         -------
    12                223
    13                223
    15                223
    12                235
    13                235
    19                235
```

Both columns are foreign keys (to the primary keys of the `volunteer` table and `event` table respectively).

Is there a better way to do this?
Should I use a compound-key as the primary key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, I don't see a problem with the way you've set it up. Tables like this are commonly used to establish one-to-many relationships between different objects. I'm doing something similar in a table that references counties and cities in a given state. (Some cities span multiple counties.)

Database design best practices state that you should declare a primary key for a table. You don't have to do this; you can technically declare a table without a primary key. However, note that many DB engines will simply create a primary key for you behind the scenes if you don't specifically declare a key; this, however, may not be ideal for every situation (and generally isn't). Specifying a primary key of your choice is good for database optimization and organization.

Due to this, I'd say that you might as well use a compound key as your primary key for your many-to-many table instead of creating a separate index column. In this situation, this will satisfy the table requirements (as a db engine will make a primary key for you regardless) and it will prevent multiple occurences of the same pair, which won't do you any good in a many-to-many reference table.

Short answer: Go with the compound primary key - `primary key(VolunteerID, EventID)`. You shouldn't go wrong.

Comment: "Because every table needs a primary key" what makes you say that?

Comment: @Conrad I say that because implementing a primary key is a part of good database design; the database uses the primary key as the main index for organizing and searching the data within a table (and in some cases, the primary key determines how the data is written on disk). If you do not specify a primary key, many database engines will silently create one for you behind the scenes, so you might as well take control and specify the key yourself. (Note that by primary key, I don't mean an autoincrementing index or a surrogate key.)

Comment: @lunchmeat. I suppose I am quibbling with you. I knew what you meant, but perhaps you might consider the differnce between "every table needs..." And "as part of good database design..."

Comment: @Conrad: Edited my answer; hopefully it'll be clearer to the OP and those who come across it in the future.

Comment: @Conrad Frix - In most database circles, a set of rows does not even qualify as a table if it does not have at least one key. So, stating that a table must have a primary key, from a logical standpoint, isn't a stretch.

Comment: @Thomas "at least one key" I can buy -- Must have a *primary* key not so sure, but as I said I was quibbling anyway

Comment: @Conrad Frix - It depends on which definition of "key" you are using. In the original designs by Codd et al, if every table must have a key and a given table only has a single key, that key is the primary key. However, in the reality of implementation, this would require that unique key constraints and primary key constraints are implemented identically which in most database systems they are not. In most database systems, unique key constraints allow for one or more nulls and primary key constraints do not.

Answer (score 2):

One use for a compound UNIQUE key would be to prevent the same volunteer/event pair from appearing twice in the table. There's no need for a primary key for this.

Answer (score 1):

A good discussion on why compound primary keys should be avoided: [What are the down sides of using a composite/compound primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107404/what-are-the-down-sides-of-using-a-composite-compound-primary-key)

Comment: interesting but I think it would only apply if the table in question was referced by another table

Comment: I disagree.  Databases change all the time - there's very little overhead involved in using a surrogate primary key on every table.

Comment: Yes and no. Surrogate keys are not really part of the logical design. For any table with a surrogate key, you need another candidate key which does imply additional overhead ( the constraint on the surrogate key + the other unique constraint ).

Comment: That said, more often than not, the benefits of that additional overhead for surrogate keys far outweigh the costs.

Answer (score 1):

Given the table you've described you have three choices

1 - lunchmeat317

```
SIGNUP
-------
VolunteerId (PK)
EventId (PK)
```

2 - Ted Hopp

```
SIGNUP
-------
VolunteerId (AK1)
EventId (AK1)
```

3 - ic3b3rg

```
SIGNUP
-------
SignUpID (PK)
VolunteerId (AK1)
EventId (AK1)
```

As Thomas pointed out the main difference between 1 and 2 is that Unique doesn't stop the following.

```
   VolunteerId EventId
   ----------- -------
   null        null
   null        null
```

However if these fields don't allow nulls to begin with (and the shouldn't) then they're exactly the same.

You could also add, as ic3b3rg suggests a Surrogate key (SignUpID). But as CJ Date [notes](http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/622337.htm)  (and I'm paraphrasing) introducing an artificial, surrogate, nonvolatile key will often be a good idea, but since its often difficult to determine volatility there's no formal way to know when you really need it.

That said as long as this table is is ...

- Tracking that volunteers have signed up for events
- There won't be any other attributes that have a functional or join dependency to R(VolunteerId, EventID)

... then in the immortal words of Yogi Berra "*When you come to a fork in the road, take it*" Meaning all three choices are valid and the choice probably won't impact your system one way or another.

Personally this is how I typically do it.

```
SIGNUP
-------
SignUpID (PK)
VolunteerId (AK1) (Not Null)
EventId (AK1) (Not Null)
```

Comment: As I pointed out in my answer, one difference between 2 (not null) and 3 is that 2 allows multiple records with the same (VolunteerId, EventId) key pair. This is perhaps an advantage for 3, but there are applications where duplicates **should be** allowed (e.g., multigraphs). A disadvantage of 3 is that there's one more index (the PK) to maintain when the table data is modified. If the PK isn't used for anything at all (not even for uniqueness), then it's just overhead that can be done without.